# Change D3 scale from linear to pow by pushing a button

Tags: d3.js

I try to switch from linear scale to pow scale dynamically by pushing a button. My setup is the following:

```
<button id="scaling">Switch from linear to quadratic scale</button>
```

with the following snippet of code:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([50, 350]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient('bottom')
    .scale(xScale);
```

and the event handler for the button:

```
d3.select("#scaling").on("click", function() {
    xScale = d3.scale.pow().exponent(2); // <-- this doesn't work!
    vis.select('.xaxis').transition().call(xAxis);
});
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/stefanooo/90zc22fm/ for a demo.

How do I achieve the changed scaling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the new scale to the axis. You should also set domain/range for the new scale:

```
xScale = d3.scale.pow().exponent(2)
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([50, 350]);
vis.select('.xaxis').transition().call(xAxis.scale(xScale));
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/90zc22fm/1/).